# If you eat it you will die

Tags: riddle

What do the poor have,
The rich need,
And if you eat it you will die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is....

> Nothing!

(Self explanatory)

Comment: I would say you ought to expand upon your answer, but looking at the question, there's not much to go on.

Comment: This is it. The poor have nothing.  The rich need nothing.  If you eat nothing you will die.

Comment: There are many times when I have eaten nothing, yet I didn't die.  Also the poor have lots of things, and the rich need lots of things.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the answer could be

> Humbleness

You know,

> Majority of poor people have it, majority of rich people need.

And if you eat it, you will die

> I was not so sure about this, but the **humble bee** has poison that *may* produce tachycardia and eventually death, if swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

> Hunger

What do the poor have?

> Poor people don't have anything to eat usually.

The rich need.

> Rich people need hunger to understand mood of poor people.

If you eat it you will die.

> If you eat nothing for a long time, you will die.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is:

> Nothing

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> Token change (coins)?